# What is the MLE for centered Gaussian:$ S_y=\frac{1}{n}\boldsymbol{X}^T\boldsymbol{X}$ or $S_y=\frac{1}{n}\boldsymbol{XX}^T$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, maximum-likelihood

What is the Maximum Likelihood Estimator  (MLE) for the centered ($\mu=0$) multivariate Gaussian?

My book gives the MLE as $$
S_y=\frac{1}{n}\boldsymbol{X}^T\boldsymbol{X}
$$
while I've seen online resources derive the MLE as $$
S_y=\frac{1}{n}\boldsymbol{XX}^T
$$

The context is to use PCA:
$$\boldsymbol{X}=\boldsymbol{U\Sigma V}^T$$ and if the first definition is used, I would get the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of  $\boldsymbol{U}$ while $\boldsymbol{V}$ if the second definition is used.

Comment: The two definitions may not have the same notation for what $\mathbf X$ means!

Comment: @TedShifrin do you mean the position that $x_i$ occupies in $\boldsymbol{X}$ ?

Comment: I mean that one may have the vectors $\mathbf x_i$ as columns and the other as rows.